# Can someone explain me why awk's sub() / gsub() works like this?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I know `awk` can do text/string substitution with `sub()` and `gsub()` like:

```
kent$ echo "fffff"|awk '{gsub("f", "b")}1'
bbbbb
```

or

```
kent$ echo "fffff"|awk '{gsub(/f/, "b")}1'
bbbbb
```

However today I made a typo mistake, I wrote the line as:

```
kent$ echo "fffff"|awk '{gsub('f', "b")}1'
```

But `awk` didn't complain about that but generated output as usual, of course, unexpected output, it took me sometime to find out the error. The output `awk` gave me was:

```
bfbfbfbfbfb
```

another example:

```
kent$ echo "fafafafafXX"|awk '{gsub('fa', "B")}1'
BfBaBfBaBfBaBfBaBfBXBXB
```

example with `sub()` is strange too:

```
kent$  echo "thanks in advance"|awk '{sub('a', "B")}1'
Bthanks in advance
```

Could someone explain me how was the strange substitution done?

```
kent$  awk --version
GNU Awk 4.0.2
```

**EDIT**

thanks for the answer from Joni. maybe this example explains it better, I just add it here:

```
kent$  echo "thanks in advance"|awk '{f="k";sub('f', "B")}1'
thanBs in advance

kent$  echo "thanks in advance"|awk '{sub('th ank', "B")}1'
awk: cmd. line:2: {sub(th
awk: cmd. line:2:        ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you write

```
echo "fffff"|awk '{gsub('f', "b")}1'
```

what awk sees is `{gsub(f, "b")}1`. It interprets `f` as a variable, with an empty value, and substitutes every *empty string* in the input with b.

The empty string is found between each character and after the last one, so awk inserts a `b` after each `f`.

You can substitute `//` or `""` for the same effect, without an unused variable:

```
echo "fffff"|awk '{gsub(//, "b")}1'            # fbfbfbfbfb
```

Comment: I am thinking this could be a trick to be used, even if it is a bit risky. :)